# iOS: Memory consumption for data type allocation

Tags: ios, objective-c

It may be a basic question but just curious to know the answer. How much memory will be occupied when we are creating each variable like int, NSString, NSDictionary, NSData etc. in our iOS Obj C program. I hope, it will be similar to C program based on the size of the data type (or) differently ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't.  At least not in a useful fashion.

Just about every class will have any number of allocations that are not directly credited to the instance's allocation directly.   As well, many classes -- `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSString` -- are actually a part of a *class cluster* and, thus, what is actually allocated is a subclass.    Finally, for the various collection and data classes, the size of the associated allocations are going to vary wildly based on their contents.   Some classes -- `UIImage`, `NSData`, etc -- may contain MBs of data that isn't actually represented by a heap allocation in that they are mapping data from the filesystem.

Or, to summarize, `class_getInstanceSize()` is useless.

Instead, you need to focus on the memory usage of your app as a systemic characteristic of its operating behavior.  The Allocations Instrument can do a good job of measuring memory usage and, more importantly, help you identify what is responsible for consumption therein.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the size of Objective-C objects an implementation detail that you can't rely on. They may happen to be consistent from one environment to another, but they offer no guarantee of that. Further, there's no consistent and complete way for you to measure their size since they may be implemented in all kinds of clever ways.

If you need precise management of memory allocations, just use C types, which are themselves entirely valid Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the size of any class by calling this, an example:

```
#import "objc/runtime.h"
int size = class_getInstanceSize([NSDictionary class]);
```

Comment: That is pretty much guaranteed to *never* return useful information.  First, `NSDictionary` is an abstract class and, thus, you never have instances of that actual class.  Secondly, `NSDictionary` -- like just about every other class -- has backing stores that are allocated separately from the allocation of the instance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of content you would like to put into this classes (NSString, NSDictionary, NSData). You can say that NSMutableString and etc changes theirs sizes, but they just reallocates themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The below document by Apple developer site will be helpful for you.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html